# Test.js is not passing the destructing ES6 program

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a simple destructure program of assigning array value in hackerrank but everytime I am getting an npm error with no error statement (only this- that file is a common js module)

```
var states = ['ABC', ['XYZ', 'UVW']];
let [A,B]= states;
console.log(A);
console.log(B);

exports(states);
```

The output should be [ 'ABC' ] and [ 'XYZ', 'UVW' ] only.

Can anyone give me an idea if there is any issue with this program upon running on Hackerrank.

Comment: Have you tried updating the states variable like `[['ABC'], ['XYZ', 'UVW']]`?

Comment: `exports(states)` does not make any sense.  `exports` is not a function.  It's an object.  If you're using a commonJS module, then you would do `module.exports = states` if you're trying to export the `states` object.  I don't see anything wrong with your destructuring unless you aren't running a new enough version of node.js to support destructuring.

Comment: Also, if you want help with an error, then you need to show us EXACTLY what output/error you are getting.  Also, it's unclear why NPM is involved here at all either.  You can run this with `node test.js`.

Comment: Mostly the export part is already a portion of the environment given under the hackerrank editor, and I have written other code snippets and they worked. Its only the code , how it is executed and not going by the test JS standard,

Comment: Mostly, there is an assertion error that I get: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]"><![CDATA[AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]:

Answer (score 2):

const states = [['Tamilnadu'], ['Punjab', 'Haryana']];
let [Chennai ,Chandigarh]= states;

module.exports = {Chennai ,Chandigarh};

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. If you are in node, then it should be module.exports = states;
2. The output will be:
   'ABC' and ['XYZ', 'UVW']

The first value in states is a string, the second value is an array. That's what you will get back for A and B respectively.

Comment: yeah, even if I place the first one as enclosed in array, i am getting the output normally but I guess the error is more of the conversion to ES6 from commonjs. However, I will get some info on it

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
var states = [];
var [Chennai, Chandigarh] = [[ 'Tamilnadu' ], [ 'Punjab', 'Haryana' ]];
module.exports = {states: [Chennai, Chandigarh]};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This One

```
var states = [['ABC'], ['XYZ', 'UVW']];
let [A,B]= states;
console.log(A);
console.log(B);

module.exports = {A,B};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var states = [['ABC'], ['XYZ', 'UVW']];
let [A,B]= states;
console.log(A);
console.log(B);

module.exports = {states};
```

This is the refreshed code which is still giving the error

Comment: Why post an answer to your own question only to state that the problem persists?  And who would upvote this?  This answer should be deleted.  If you have an update to your question, post it in the question so that all readers see the same problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var states = [['Tamilnadu'], ['Punjab', 'Haryana']];

const [Chennai, Chandigarh] = states;

module.exports = {Chennai,Chandigarh}
```

Try this one.

Comment: If this work add your comment

Answer (score 0):

const states =['Tamilnadu','Punjab','Haryana'];

Const [Chennai,...Chandigarh]= states;

module.exports = {Chennai ,Chandigarh};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const states=[['Tamilnadu'],['Punjab','Haryana']];
var [Chennai ,Chandigarh]=states;
module.exports={Chennai ,Chandigarh}
```

This will work